# SAS Library not showing all datasets existing in unix folder

Tags: unix, dataset, sas

I have unix folder containing about 700 sas datasets. 
When I assign a library to this folder, I am able to view only 30 of the 700 datasets. I checked unix permissions for the datasets and see no difference between the ones that are visible and the ones that are not.

1) This is a pre-assigned library in SAS Management console.
2) The Datasets are still accessible if i name them in data and proc steps,Just not visible in the library.

Comment: try enabling special characters within table or column object names while registering tables from the preassigned library..i guess that should solve your problem

Comment: It didnt work. I tried copying all the datasets to a different folder and reassigning a new libname to the new folder. Now I am able to see a different subset of datasets. But still not all of them. THe strange part is if I refresh the library in EG during the file transfer, I am able to see all the files copied until then. After the file copy completes, It again resets to display a subset of the original files.

Comment: Wild guess. Any chance the datasets you can't see have mixed case file names?

Comment: When you say you can't see them, how/where are you looking?  Any interesting log messages when you registered the datasets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with partial listing of SAS datasets in SAS library is finally resolved with the help of SAS Support.

This is the response  I got from them:

“The problem is related to Swedish characters in SAS filenames, we have renamed the 3 files with Swedish characters and then all tables is showing
We still don’t know why this is happening and will register a support track regarding this.
As a workaround all personnel  should not save filenames with Swedish Characters while we investigate why this is happening”.

For example out of 700 datasets, 3 had filenames containing the special character ä. This was somehow having an impact on the Listing in SAS EG and Proc Contents. When it was replaced, all 700 files automatically started appearing.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the library references for local and unix libraries. they should be exactly similar. then only we can see the datasets in window environment.